# Typescript Knex Config (!parsedConfig.client && !parsedConfig.dialect)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, knex.js

I am building an express backend with TypeScript, knex, postgres and heroku. Right now I am trying to connect my frontend website with the backend, to insert data into my database (pg, heroku)

I just migrated my JS files (knexfile.js, dbconfig.js) to TypeScript and didn't have the problem before. Seems to have sth. to do with my dbconfig file.

When trying to start my express server I am getting the following response: \server\node_modules\knex\lib\knex-builder\internal\config-resolver.js:20
(!parsedConfig.client && !parsedConfig.dialect)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

Any idea?

files are as follows:

**db-config.ts**

```
dotenv.config();

import Knex from "knex";
const dbEnvironment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

const config = require("../knexfile.ts")[dbEnvironment];

export default Knex(config);
```

**knexfile.ts**

```
//require("dotenv").config(); // old js
//const pg = require("pg"); //-> old js

import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import pg from "pg";

import { Knex } from "knex";

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  pg.defaults.ssl = { rejectUnauthorized: false };
}

const defaults = {
  client: "pg",
  migrations: { directory: "./db/migrations" },
  seeds: { directory: "./db/seeds" },
};

const knexConfig = {
  development: {
    ...defaults,
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    },
  },
  production: {
    ...defaults,
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: { min: 2, max: 10 },
  },
};

const testConfig: Knex.Config = {
  client: "pg",
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  },
  migrations: { directory: "./db/migrations" },
  seeds: { directory: "./db/seeds" },
};

export default testConfig;
```

**index.ts**

```
import TripService from "./api/TripService";
import * as OpenApiValidator from "express-openapi-validator";
import { HttpError } from "express-openapi-validator/dist/framework/types";

import { knex as knexDriver } from "knex";
import cors from "cors";
import testConfig from "./db/db-config";

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const knex = knexDriver(testConfig);
const tripService = new TripService(knex);

app.use(
 cors({
   origin: "*", //allow requests from any origin for now
 })
);

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
 OpenApiValidator.middleware({
   apiSpec: "./openapi.yaml",
   validateRequests: true, // (default)
   validateResponses: false, // false by default
 })
);

app.use((err: HttpError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
 // format error
 res.status(err.status || 500).json({
   message: err.message,
   errors: err.errors,
 });
});

app.post("/trips", (req, res) => {
 const payload = req.body;
 tripService.add(payload).then((savedTrip) => res.json(savedTrip));
});

app.get("/trips", (req, res) => {
 tripService.getAll().then((savedTrips) => res.json(savedTrips));
});

app.delete("/trips/:tripId", (req, res) => {
 const tripId = req.params.tripId;
 tripService.delete(tripId).then(() => {
   res.status(204);
   res.send();
 });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: ok solved it by not using the db-config.ts